# Помогите написать регекс для валидации строки математического выражения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

`re.test(str)` должен вернуть `true` если строка состоит только из чисел и знаков `×÷+-`. `+` и `-` могут идти друг за другом например `5+-2` или `5-+2`, но `+`,`-` не могут идти сразу до `×`,`÷` (могут только после). И `×÷` тоже не могут идти друг за другом. В общем все как в математике.

```
'5+-3÷2' // true
'5×÷4+2' // false
'5/-5' // true
'5-/5' // false
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128496/discussion-on-question-by-hot-penguin------).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
let math_check = exp => !(/[\^*%+/÷-]+(?=[\^*%/÷]+)/.test(exp));

console.log(math_check("^^5*÷6*555*7")); // false
console.log(math_check("5+1--1")); // true
console.log(math_check("6-/68")); // false
```

Регексп использует опережающую проверку. "Найти X, после которого следует Y" В данном случае, найти арифметический оператор, после которого следует другой, который этого не может делать. Как то так.

Простейшее регулярное выражение, которое пришло в голову.

Comment: Очень круто спасибо, работает с разными знаками деления и умножения

Answer (score 4):

```js
const re = /^([-+]?\d+[-+×÷]?)*[-+]?\d+$/;


console.log(re.test('5+-3÷2')); // true
console.log(re.test('5÷-4+2')); // true
console.log(re.test('5×÷4+2')); // false
console.log(re.test('5/-5'));   // false
console.log(re.test('5÷-5'));   // true
console.log(re.test('5-/5'));   // false
console.log(re.test('5-÷5'));   // false
```

Answer (score 4):

Возможно, не очень эффективно, зато интересно тем, что тут именно исключаются запрещённые сочетания, а не формируются разрешённые:

```js
const re = /^(?!.*(\D[×÷]))(?=.*\d)[-+×÷\d]+$/;

console.log(re.test('5+-3÷2')); // true
console.log(re.test('5÷-4+2')); // true
console.log(re.test('5×÷4+2')); // false
console.log(re.test('5/-5'));   // false
console.log(re.test('5÷-5'));   // true
console.log(re.test('5-/5'));   // false
console.log(re.test('5-÷5'));   // false
```

Answer (score 2):

Унарные операции привязываем к числу, а после числа требуем конец строки или бинарный оператор:

```js
const re = /^(([-+]*\d+)($|[-+×÷](?!$)))*$/;


console.log(re.test('5+-3÷2')); // true
console.log(re.test('5÷-4+2')); // true
console.log(re.test('5×÷4+2')); // false
console.log(re.test('5/-5'));   // false
console.log(re.test('5÷-5'));   // true
console.log(re.test('5-/5'));   // false
console.log(re.test('5-÷5'));   // false
```

Answer (score 0):

я думаю что вам нужно только указать неправильные выражения разделены по символа | и экранировать символы как / и * с \ например:

```
"-\/|\/\*|\*\/"
```

найдет

```
-/, /*, */
```

в тексте:

```
5+2-/3/*8*/6
```